# Pretty forms in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I use bootstrap3 with forms of django? I can add class to label tag, but can't to input.

```
{{ form.my_field.errors }}
<label class="control-label" for="{{ form.my_field.id_for_label }}">My field</label>
{{ form.my_field }}
```

Comment: You might find the [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) app useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your forms code, you can specify the class using the `widgets` argument in the form field `my_field`.

**For example:**

Lets say there is a field `name` in my form `SomeForm` and we want the `name` widget to have some  CSS class `my_css_class`, then to do this, we can use the [`Widget.attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) argument when creating the widget. This will add the `my_css_class` to the field `name`.

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'my_css_class'}))
```

Comment: This way is legal, but I think it's not very good, because this way unites front-end with back-end. Or am I not right?

Comment: I think its okay if you do like this as Django itself has mentioned this method in its official docs. Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs). It has given you the flexibility to define the class using your backend code also.